# Linux gateway with one interface and aliases

Tags: networking, iptables, router, gateway

Hello I am trying to use a linux machine as gateway for other machines in the same network using iptables, these are the configurations related to both machines:

- **Machine A** (This is the one I want to use as gateway)

```
root@router-1:~# sysctl -p
net.ipv4.ip_forward = 1
net.ipv6.conf.all.forwarding = 1
```

```
root@router-1:~# ip a
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether f2:3c:91:58:5b:fb brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 172.105.89.xxx/24 brd 172.105.89.255 scope global eth0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet 192.168.159.203/17 brd 192.168.255.255 scope global eth0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 2a01:7e01::f03c:91ff:fe58:5bfb/64 scope global dynamic mngtmpaddr noprefixroute 
       valid_lft 2591978sec preferred_lft 604778sec
    inet6 fe80::f03c:91ff:fe58:5bfb/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

And I have the following iptables rules:

```
# Generated by iptables-save v1.6.1 on Thu Aug  1 06:42:26 2019
*mangle
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [729:54316]
:INPUT ACCEPT [729:54316]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [539:62761]
:POSTROUTING ACCEPT [539:62761]
COMMIT
# Completed on Thu Aug  1 06:42:26 2019
# Generated by iptables-save v1.6.1 on Thu Aug  1 06:42:26 2019
*filter
:INPUT ACCEPT [493:36634]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [373:47212]
-A FORWARD -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
COMMIT
# Completed on Thu Aug  1 06:42:26 2019
# Generated by iptables-save v1.6.1 on Thu Aug  1 06:42:26 2019
*nat
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [28:1501]
:INPUT ACCEPT [28:1501]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [5:397]
:POSTROUTING ACCEPT [2:161]
-A POSTROUTING -s 192.168.128.0/17 ! -d 192.168.128.0/17 -j MASQUERADE
COMMIT
# Completed on Thu Aug  1 06:42:26 2019
```

- **Machine B**:

```
root@client:~# ip a
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether f2:3c:91:58:5b:62 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.157.248/17 brd 192.168.255.255 scope global eth0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 2a01:7e01::f03c:91ff:fe58:5b62/64 scope global mngtmpaddr dynamic 
       valid_lft 2591988sec preferred_lft 604788sec
    inet6 fe80::f03c:91ff:fe58:5b62/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

```
root@client:~# ip r
default via 192.168.159.203 dev eth0 onlink 
192.168.128.0/17 dev eth0 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.157.248

root@client:~# ping 192.168.159.203
PING 192.168.159.203 (192.168.159.203) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 192.168.159.203: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.773 ms
```

So the client machine can ping the gateway machine as they are in the same subnet but any other IP outside of the subnet is not reachable.

Comment: Is IP Forwarding enabled on the gateway ? You can check it with : `sysctl net.ipv4.ip_forward`. If it show `0` then you have to enable it with `sysctl -w net.ipv4.ip_forward=1` or `echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward`. To make these changes permanent : write `net.ipv4.ip_forward = 1` in `/etc/sysctl.conf`, then `sysctl -p /etc/sysctl.conf`. You may need to restart the network.

Comment: Yes sorry I forgot to mention that, let me update the question

Comment: did you consider the fact that everything from 192.168.128.1 to 192.168.255.254 is considered to be on the local net and not subject to Routing due to the /17 netmask? which addresses did you use to test for outside Connection?

Comment: I did test many public IPs like the one given by: nslookup google.es (216.58.201.163).

What sounds interesting is the fact you mention about the internal network, I don't really know which rules should I use to achieve the goal of having this machine A as a router for the other machines but I guess that is possible no ?

Comment: Sure. Any IP outside the range i mentioned will do. Try to use 'tcpdump -v -s0 -X -e eth0' on the router machine, and check source- and destination addresses of the outgoing packets. Also check if the Gateway set as Default  (propably 172.105..) on the router can be reached from there.

Answer (score 0):

You may need to SNAT (Source NAT) your internal network:

```
-A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j eth0_masq
-A eth0_masq -s 192.168.158.203/17 -j SNAT --to-source 172.105.89.xxx/24
```

Where '.89.xxx' is the public IP address you'd like to use from your public IP address range for outbound connections.

Answer (score 0):

At the end, I found out my configuration was ok.

The problem was the provider which blocks the traffic to avoid spoofing.